# Node.js code hints

Tags: node.js, express, module, redis, export

Hello I would like to know if I'm right with this kind of code and if there is a better way to do it.

There is a module to get the homepage.

app.js:

```
[...]
// Get homepage
app.get('/', frontend.index);
[...]
```

The frontend.index function have to get a couple of data obj from redis (util.getRemoteConfig and util.getGlobalStats) and use them to render the Jade template, so I did this.

frontend.js:

```
[...]
// [GET] Homepage
exports.index = function(req, res){   
    var remoteConfig = {};
    var globalStats = {};

    util.getRemoteConfig(function(remoteConfig) { 

        var version = 'n.a.';
        if (remoteConfig.version)
            version = remoteConfig.version;

        util.getGlobalStats(function(globalStats) {

            res.render('index.jade', 
                { title: config.items.default_title, version: version, global_stats: JSON.stringify(globalStats) }
            );
        });
    });     
};
[...]
```

The util module gets the data from redis and pass it via callback.

util.js:

```
[...]
exports.getRemoteConfig = function(cb) {
    client.hget('remote_config', function(err, obj) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        // do something with obj and return it
        cb(obj);
    });
};

exports.getGlobalStats = function(cb) {
    client.hgetall("global_stats", function (err, obj) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        // do something with obj and return it
        cb(obj);
    });
};
[...]
```

This is working fine but is it really correct? Can I do something better than this?

Thanks any hint will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If remote config  and global stats are route independent, you should probably put them into a middle-ware instead of controller:

middlewares.js:

```
exports.remoteConfig = function(req,res,next){
    util.getRemoteConfig(function(err,config){
        if(err){
            return next(err);
        }
        req._remote_config = config;
        return next(null);
    });
}
```

controllers.js:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){   
    var remoteConfig = req._remote_config;
    var globalStats = req._global_stats;

    res.render('index.jade', { 
        title: config.items.default_title, 
        version: version, 
        global_stats: JSON.stringify(globalStats) 
    };
};
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/', middleware.remoteConfig, middleware.globalStats,controllers.index);
```

or

```
app.use(middleware.remoteConfig);
app.use(middleware.globalStats);
```

if the middleware should be used for all routes.

Note: the code is untested.

Comment: I would probably add too that if the config is not likely to change often, then some sort of caching might be worth investing time in so you're not calling redis for every http request.

Comment: hey thank you! That's was the missing piece "middlewares"!

@Deif what kind of cache do you suggest?

Comment: An in-memory store would be fine. That is - the middleware that you now let the app use should check for a private variable before it requests the data from redis. If the private variable is populated then just return that, otherwise query redis. Then you can add expiry dates and so on if you want to regenerate the configs after a certain amount of time, etc.